# Controlling output of jobs run with gnu parallel

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

On my old machine with gnu parallel version 20121122 after I

```
parallel -j 15 < jobs.txt
```

I see output of the jobs being run which is very handy for debug purposes.

On my new machine with parallel version 20140122 then I execute above-mentioned command I see nothing in the terminal.

From another SO thread I found out about `--tollef` flag which fixes problem for me, but soon it is to be retired.  How do I keep things working after retirement of `--tollef` flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

--ungroup (if half-lines are allowed to mix - as they are with --tollef).

--line-buffer (if you only want complete lines printed - i.e. no half-line mixing).